# How do you legally sell a hardware product that uses the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, licensing

I would like to create a Linux-based OS for a VR headset that I'm developing. From what I understand, the Linux kernel uses the GPL-2 license which allows for commercial use but it also requires you to publish your source code. How is Tesla able to sell a physical product that runs on a Linux OS while also being able to keep their source code private and how can I do the same?

Comment: Aside: this is one of the reasons we ask people [not to cross-post questions on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 0):

First, the GPLv2 doesn't require you to publish the source code, it requires that you provide a written offer to provide the source code, valid for 3 years.

Then, I am not a lawyer but some will says that publishing source code is not complying with the GPLv2 because it states that this has to be done "on a medium customarily used for software interchange" which, at the time of the GPLv2 was a CD.

Finally, Tesla is distributing their source code, here: https://github.com/teslamotors